# multi same custom validator function in reactive form constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

i need a little help to know how to use the same custom validator function multiples times for different formControl in same constructor, this function uses formControl as aparameters to know if time1 > time2, and i have 3 different time formControls, but i dont know how to use the same function to validate all the formControls, this is my custom function validator:

```html
/ custom validator to check if time 1 is after time 2
export function timeIsAfter(time1Control: string, time2Control: string) {
  
    return (formGroup: FormGroup) => {
        const time1 = formGroup.controls[time1Control];
        const time2 = formGroup.controls[time2Control];

        if (time2.errors && !time2.errors.timeIsAfter) {
            // return if another validator has already found an error on the matchingControl
            return;
        }

        // set error on matchingControl if validation fails
        if (time1.value > time2.value) {
            time1.setErrors({ timeIsAfter: true });
        } else {
            time1.setErrors(null);
        }
    }
}
```

this is my form constructor:

```html
formConstructor() {
  this.frequencyForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    time_1: new FormControl(null),
    time_2: new FormControl(null),
    time_3: new FormControl(null),
    time_4: new FormControl(null),

   
  }, {
    validator: timeIsAfter('time_1', 'time_2'), // <--- this works 
    validator_2: timeIsAfter('time_3', 'time_4'), // <--- this doesnt work
  });
}
```

i tried to add with Validators.compose but dont work, also using Validators.call and i get a error

any help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an object, Set Array of validators like this.
Also set the type of the return function to `ValidatorFn`

```
formConstructor() {
    this.frequencyForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      time_1: new FormControl(null),
      time_2: new FormControl(null),
      time_3: new FormControl(null),
      time_4: new FormControl(null),
    });
    this.frequencyForm.setValidators([timeIsAfter('time_1', 'time_2'), timeIsAfter('time_3', 'time_4')])
  }

export function timeIsAfter(time1Control: string, time2Control: string) {

    return (formGroup: FormGroup): ValidatorFn => { ... }

}
```

Comment: i get this error:

 Argument of type '((formGroup: FormGroup) => void)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[]'.
  Type '((formGroup: FormGroup) => void)[]' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn[]'.
    Type '(formGroup: FormGroup) => void' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn'.
      Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ValidationErrors'.ts(2345)

Comment: Set the type of function returned to be a `ValidatorFn`